# Find minimum distance match in sub-linear time in a data base

Tags: complexity-theory, data-structures, search-algorithms

The title seems a little vague. So let me explain the question in detail.

Suppose you have a data base. Each record in the data base is $<\mathbf{x},data>$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n$-dimensional index vector.

A query is also an $n$-dimensional vector $\mathbf{y}$. So given the query $\mathbf{y}$, the data base will return the record $i$ such that $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{y}$ have minimum distance. (It can be any distance. But let's focus on Euclidean distance here).

The trivial solution is to scan every record in the data base and compute the distance. This will introduce linear complexity with regard to the number of total records in the data base.

So is there any sub-linear algorithms to solve this problem (approximately)?
For example, if the dimension $n=1$, we can organize the index in data structure such as binary search tree. But for dimension $n>1$, can we also organize the index into some special data structure?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: I found some solutions such as organizing the index into R-trees or kd-trees.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is exactly solved by the [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which organizes points in $k$ dimensions with logarithmic lookup time.

Comment: The k-d tree is indeed relevant, but there are no guarantees that you can find the nearest neighbor in logarithmic lookup time -- in fact, the lookup time can be arbitrarily bad.   You might be thinking of results that *if* the points in the database are randomly distributed then finding a nearest neighbor might take logarithmic time (I can't personally vouch for that), but that's a significant "if" -- in practice data often isn't distributed randomly.

Comment: @D.W. The wiki mentioned logarithmic average time, that's why I mentioned it. Does there exist _any_ data structure with guaranteed logarithmic time nearest neighbour search in the worst case? If not, is it proven to be impossible?

Comment: As far as I know, no such data structure is known.  Due to the curse of dimensionality, the situation is very hard, in high dimensions.  I don't know what the current-best results on worst-case complexity on nearest-neighbor search are, but if I recall correctly, they're pretty bad, and I have a recollection that it's hard to beat the trivial linear-scan algorithm in practice if the number of dimensions is large.